# Unable to integrate Google Cloud Messaging with Android Project on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add Google Cloud Messaging to my app on Android Studio, but I seem to be unable to integrate with the library. The code for my build.gradle file is below, which I modified on the basis of suggestions here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup

I should mention that I am also using Google+ login, which is not facing any issues.

The app is unable to find the required files for GCM inside `com.google.android.gms` (specifically `common.ConnectionResult`, `common.GooglePlayServicesUtil` and `gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging`) while importing.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("release.keystore")
            storePassword "****"
            keyAlias "****"
            keyPassword "****"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    // You must install or update the Google Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // The Google Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
}
```

Comment: what is the min SDK version in library?

Comment: What version of Android Studio is this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure what your issue is, but the imports you are missing come from google play services.  You can list the classes from this jar on a Mac or Linux with this (or a similar) command:

```
jar tvf "/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar" | grep 'gms/common'
```

The build.gradle below works fine with my code that uses Google Cloud Messaging:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```